# as3 Why use starling for games on Android and IOS devices?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5, starling-framework

I have a nice setup where I publish, compile, design, etc. in Flash Pro CS5.5 and write as3 code (and some xml) in Sulbime Text 2.

Being forced to import each image or generate a sprite sheet seems like a such a hassle for nothing.

My apk apps work fine use mouse events, so what's the point in switching to starling?

Comment: There's no need to switch if you're happy with how your application or game performs. Starling is a library that allows the use of hardware accelerated graphics via the new Stage3D API, allowing you to create much more complex and high performance projects.

Comment: yes, its true. Also, on Android, there is a wide range of devices.. It may be that your Samsung SII phone does well, but the SI will struggle, and lagg. If you use starling, more devices will run it smooth. Starling is used by Angry Birds on Facebook, because it ensures that older pc-s will run it smooth. It has nothing to do with mouseevents. It has to do a lot with rendering.

Comment: Wait a minute. I just tried to test an app on my android phone that had a simple color shape tween, but on the phone it just snapped to the second color at the last frame. Is it the case that tweens made in the Flash IDE don't work on AIR applications?? If so, then that is a HUGE reason to use starling.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer you with 3 letters **FPS**.

You are getting a big boost in performance as you are working with law level API of [Adobe Stage3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html). And you do not need to worry about how to handle it because starling is warping it for you with nice 2D game Engine.

I suggest you to work with Starling for core game development and [Gazman SDK](http://gazman-sdk.com) for UI.

How ever there is one problem with starling. It does not have native support for vectors, so scaling could be a problem in many cases, spatially when building android application that you want to support in many screen resolutions. You can read this [post](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/multi-resolution_development) about starling solution for that problem.